# Expected ')' JS error in IE after assigning a value to a function argument

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, compiler-errors

I wrote the below code in my JS file and IE is giving error for the argument '**searchMap**' when I am assigning value for it in the function.

```
mapping: function (mappingObj,searchMap=false) {
// code 
}
```

Error is : `Expected ')'`

Comment: `searchMap=false` is invalid syntax

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You are using [default parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters).
It is a feature of ES6, and [**IE** does not support this](https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-javascript_functions_default_parameters).

I would suggest to convert your code to ES5, like..

```
mapping: function (mappingObj, searchMap) {
   if (!searchMap) searchMap = false;
}
```

Comment: This should be included in JS101... Even IE11 doesn't support this :/

Comment: IE EDGE also doesn't support this. that's why i'm here, sadly :(

Comment: @Amjo It does in the latest edge now.

Comment: Correction, IE is dead. Microsoft is switching to blink browser with v8 engine now. But if you still use IE, this answer is still relevant.

Answer (score 0):

```
var searchMap = false;
mapping: function(mappingObj, searchMap) {
    // code
}

mapping(mappingObj, searchMap);
```

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this".