# Function with parameter set to default value not working in Internet Explorer but works fine on Firefox

Tags: javascript

I'm using the updated versions of Firefox 62.0.3 and Internet Explorer 11.0.85. I have a simple code which works on Firefox but not in internet explorer.

**The html file get_name.html**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>test onsubmit on ie</title> 
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src = "myscript.js"> </script>
    </head>

    <body>

        <form id="formId" action="#" name="getName" onsubmit="return(displayAnswer('Lion'))"> 

            <p><input type="submit" value="SUBMIT" />&nbsp;&nbsp; 

        </form>

        <span style="font-size: xx-large">Name sent to Fucntion: </span><label style="font-size: x-large" name = "displayName" id = "lblName"></label>
    </body>
</html>
```

**javascript file myscript.js**

```
function displayAnswer (defaultVal = "Tiger") {

     document.getElementById('lblName').innerHTML =  defaultVal;
     return false;
}
```

So if you run the html file in Firefox it works perfectly fine and prints the passed argument onto the Label, but it won't work on Internet Explorer

**But if i have the function as this**

```
function displayAnswer (defaultVal ) {

    document.getElementById('lblName').innerHTML =  defaultVal;
    return false;
}
```

Then it works on both browsers. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Default parameters are not supported in Internet Explorer. See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters#Browser_compatibility).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Expected ')' JS error in IE after assigning a value to a function argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38429977/expected-js-error-in-ie-after-assigning-a-value-to-a-function-argument)

Comment: thank you @RobbyCornelissen, now i know why.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because IE does not support default parameters. 
For more details have a look at the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters#Browser_compatibility).